# Makeindex number sorting

Tags: numbering, indexing, sorting

I would like to change the standard number sorting of makeindex.

Standard sorting output:
1.1, 1
1.2, 1
10.4, 1
12.2, 1
2.2, 1
3.3, 1
4.4, 1

Requested sorting output:
1.1, 1
1.2, 1
2.2, 1
3.3, 1
4.4, 1
10.4, 1
12.2, 1

Here is a mini example of the standard sorting which produces the above mentioned standard sorting output.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Refering to OM A 1.1\index{OM A!1.1}.\\
Refering to OM A 1.2\index{OM A!1.2}.\\
Refering to OM A 2.2\index{OM A!2.2}.\\
Refering to OM A 10.4\index{OM A!10.4}.\\
Refering to OM A 3.3\index{OM A!3.3}.\\
Refering to OM A 4.4\index{OM A!4.4}.\\
Refering to OM A 12.2\index{OM A!12.2}.\\
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `makeindex`, you may add a sorting key inside your `\index` macros. Just add as many leading zeros as needed to fill up to the width of the largest number:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Refering to OM A 1.1\index{OM A!01.01@1.1}.\\
Refering to OM A 1.2\index{OM A!01.02@1.2}.\\
Refering to OM A 2.2\index{OM A!02.02@2.2}.\\
Refering to OM A 10.4\index{OM A!10.04@10.4}.\\
Refering to OM A 3.3\index{OM A!03.03@3.3}.\\
Refering to OM A 4.4\index{OM A!04.04@4.4}.\\
Refering to OM A 12.2\index{OM A!12.02@12.2}.\\
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is pretty cool, thanks a lot. I will use that solution. To sum up, the sorting key is between !...@, and after the @ is the displayed number on the index.

Comment: @Speedwing Yes, exactly :-)

Answer (score 5):

Although the question was about `makeindex`, I'll show a solution with `xindy` and using `imakeidx` for automatic numerical sorting of the index.

One - column index is achieved by `columns=-1`, the letter group heading can be switched off by dumping `\lettergroup` to do do nothing after `\theindex` started.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\apptocmd{\theindex}{\newcommand{\lettergroup}[1]{}}{}{}%
\makeindex[options={-M numeric-sort.xdy},columns=1]
\begin{document}
Refering to OM A 1.1\index{OM A!1.1}.\\
Refering to OM A 1.2\index{OM A!1.2}.\\
Refering to OM A 2.2\index{OM A!2.2}.\\R
Refering to OM A 10.4\index{OM A!10.4}.\\
Refering to OM A 3.3\index{OM A!3.3}.\\
Refering to OM A 4.4\index{OM A!4.4}.\\
Refering to OM A 12.2\index{OM A!12.2}.\\
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May thanks, that is a good alternative. What bothers me is that it has 2 columns and the 'O' is displayed on top of 'OM A'.

Comment: @Speedwing: The number of columns can be specified as an option to `\makeindex`: `[columns=1]`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint. What about to hide the 'O' in top of 'OM A'?

Comment: By the way, I just found out, that on my system (TEX Maker 4.2, LatexMk compiler -> TexLive 2013, Windows 7) it does not work to get the correct number sorting as in the picture above. Furthermore it does not show the 'O' in top of 'OM A', when I compile your example... How come?

Comment: @Speedwing: I neither use texmaker,latexmk,tl2013 and windows 7, so there is nothing I can say about why there is a wrong sorting and the 'missing' letter group opener 'O', I am sorry