# Padding number with spaces to proper sort index

Tags: formatting, indexing, sorting

Indexing by numbers is done well by makeindex (or imakeidx) except when you add text emphasis (bold or italic) as seen in the picture.  In order to force a proper sort on the second group, I would like to pad the numbers with extra spaces assuming the number will have only 3 digits, for example a macro variable \padthreedigits in the line

```
\index[test]{{\bfseries{#3}}!\textit{\padthreedigits{#2}}: #1}
```

Following is an example (Parameter #2 is the target for padding)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\newcommand{\addreftoindex}[3]{
    % ** This is the offending line
    \index[test]{{\bfseries{#3}}!\textit{#2}: #1}
}
\makeindex
\makeindex[title=My Index, columnseprule, name=test]

\begin{document}

    Lorem Ipsum is \addreftoindex{book 1}{5}{Author 15} simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 

    To show that getvalue works, \addreftoindex{book 1}{9}{Author 15}I want the bookname I cited here: \addreftoindex{book 1}{11}{Author 15}

    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the~1500s,  
    when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
    specimen book. 

    It \addreftoindex{book 9}{9}{Author 01}has survived not only \addreftoindex{book 9}{1}{Author 01}five centuries, but \addreftoindex{book 9}{11}{Author 01}also the leap into 
    electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. Now add the reference 

    \printindex[test]   
\end{document}
```

[image: Sorting Numbers for Indexing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `\indexdigits` holds the length of "999" `\padthreedigits` could be defined as

```
\newcommand\padthreedigits[1]{\hbox to \indexdigits{\hfill#1}}
```

With your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\newdimen\indexdigits
\setbox0\hbox{999}
\indexdigits\wd0
\newcommand\padthreedigits[1]{\hbox to \indexdigits{\hfill#1}}
\newcommand{\addreftoindex}[3]{
    \index[test]{{\bfseries{#3}}!\textit{\padthreedigits{#2}}: #1}
}
\makeindex
\makeindex[title=My Index, columnseprule, name=test]

\begin{document}

    Lorem Ipsum is \addreftoindex{book 1}{5}{Author 15} simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 

    To show that getvalue works, \addreftoindex{book 1}{9}{Author 15}I want the bookname I cited here: \addreftoindex{book 1}{11}{Author 15}

    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the~1500s,  
    when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
    specimen book. 

    It \addreftoindex{book 9}{9}{Author 01}has survived not only \addreftoindex{book 9}{1}{Author 01}five centuries, but \addreftoindex{book 9}{11}{Author 01}also the leap into 
    electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. Now add the reference 

    \printindex[test]   
\end{document}
```

Finally, regarding the sorting of the index you would say

```
\newcommand{\addreftoindex}[3]{
  \index[test]{{\bfseries{#3}}!#2@\textit{\padthreedigits{#2}}: #1}
}
```

[image: output]

Comment: It pads the numbers but does not solve the sorting problem as requested

Comment: @hpcolos -- I think you asked two more or less unrelated questions. In fact, the sorting questions has been solved a long time ago: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205340/makeindex-number-sorting. However, I added the requested bit.

Comment: Now with the addition your solution (and egreg's) includes padding and sorting.  Thanks

Comment: @hpcolos -- youre welcome, mate!

Answer (score 4):

Consider using an `<sort by>@<entry>` notation if `<entry>` may contain odd things and should instead be sorted by `<sort by>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\newcommand{\addreftoindex}[3]{
  % ** This is the offending line
  \index[test]{{\bfseries{#3}}!#2@\makebox[0pt][r]{\textit{#2}}: #1}
}

\makeindex[title=My Index, columnseprule, name=test]

\begin{document}

Lorem Ipsum is \addreftoindex{book 1}{5}{Author 15} simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 

To show that getvalue works, \addreftoindex{book 1}{9}{Author 15}I want the bookname I cited here: \addreftoindex{book 1}{11}{Author 15}

Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the~1500s,  
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
specimen book. 

It \addreftoindex{book 9}{9}{Author 01}has survived not only \addreftoindex{book 9}{1}{Author 01}five centuries, 
but \addreftoindex{book 9}{11}{Author 01}also the leap into 
electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. Now add the reference 

\printindex[test]

\end{document}
```

The formatting of the element has been set `r`ight-aligned within a zero-width box. You can change the `0pt` to something larger to move the items further to the right.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to use `@`; we also want that the macros are not untimely expanded.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=My Index, columnseprule, name=test]

\newrobustcmd{\addreftoindex}[3]{%
  \index[test]{\formatauthor{#3}!#2@\padnumber{#2}: #1}%
}
\newrobustcmd{\formatauthor}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newrobustcmd{\padnumber}[1]{%
  \textit{\ifnum#1<10 \hphantom{00}\else\ifnum#1<100 \hphantom{0}\fi\fi#1}%
}


\begin{document}

Lorem Ipsum is \addreftoindex{book 1}{5}{Author 15} simply dummy text 
of the printing and typesetting industry. 

To show that getvalue works, \addreftoindex{book 1}{9}{Author 15}I want 
the bookname I cited here: \addreftoindex{book 1}{11}{Author 15}

Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the~1500s,  
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
specimen book. 

It \addreftoindex{book 9}{9}{Author 01}has survived not only 
\addreftoindex{book 9}{1}{Author 01}five centuries, 
but \addreftoindex{book 9}{11}{Author 01}also the leap into 
electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. Now add the reference.

\printindex[test]

\end{document}
```

Here's the contents of `test.idx` (the raw index file):

```
\indexentry{\formatauthor {Author 15}!5@\padnumber {5}: book 1}{1}
\indexentry{\formatauthor {Author 15}!9@\padnumber {9}: book 1}{1}
\indexentry{\formatauthor {Author 15}!11@\padnumber {11}: book 1}{1}
\indexentry{\formatauthor {Author 01}!9@\padnumber {9}: book 9}{1}
\indexentry{\formatauthor {Author 01}!1@\padnumber {1}: book 9}{1}
\indexentry{\formatauthor {Author 01}!11@\padnumber {11}: book 9}{1}
```

and here `test.ind` (the sorted and processed file):

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item \formatauthor {Author 01}
    \subitem \padnumber {1}: book 9, 1
    \subitem \padnumber {9}: book 9, 1
    \subitem \padnumber {11}: book 9, 1
  \item \formatauthor {Author 15}
    \subitem \padnumber {5}: book 1, 1
    \subitem \padnumber {9}: book 1, 1
    \subitem \padnumber {11}: book 1, 1

\end{theindex}
```

[image]

You can adjust the definition of `\subitem` if you want a smaller indentation. For instance,

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\subitem}{\@idxitem\hspace*{10pt}}
\makeatother
```

would halve the indentation (prior to the space for the three digits).